# jQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

Can anyone help with a jQuery snippet that would use Ajax to pull an XML file in on page load?

Have really clunky way of doing it without jQuery here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function  loadXMLDoc()
{
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
      xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
      var txt = "";
      x = mlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title");
      for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
        txt = txt + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br />";
      }
    document.getElementById("checkedIn").innerHTML=txt;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "data.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Ideally rather the having a click generate the list it would do so on page load, showing the fields from the XML (title, author, and whether it is checked in or not)

Would hug you for a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$( function() {
 $.ajax( { 
     url: 'ajax.xml',
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'xml',
     success: function( response ) {
        var books = $( response ).find( 'book' );
        var list = $( '#booklist' );
        $( books ).each( function() {
            var checkedOut = ( $( this ).attr( 'checked-out' ) == '1' );
            var title = $( this ).find( 'title' );
            var li = $( '<li></li>');
            if( checkedOut ) {
               li.addClass( 'selected' );
            }
            li.html( title );
            list.append( li );
        });
     }
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, stumbled upon this shortly after asking via jQuery website...makes perfect sense. But I'm just not familiar enough with JS to actually write my success function. How might I display all the resulting <titles> from the XML file as a li in a ul named #booklist, then check if the <book> from the XML has a checked-in="0" or 1 and give them a different class on their li?

Comment: @Banderdash, What does your XML look like?

Comment: @Banderdash, what is it that you want to display?

Comment: I'd just like to show the title's from the XML in a list, and then add a class to a specific list-item of that "book" has checked-out="1"

Comment: I feel like we are close, http://clients.pixelbleed.net/ajax-test/ but not working?

Comment: @Banderdash, I'm waiting for you... :)

Comment: Sorry! Had a quick bite to eat. Really appreciate you working with me on this. I've updated your update but it's still not outputting, any ideas? Maybe try test at http://jsbin.com ?

Comment: I'm going to try to get the XML file and do it locally.

Comment: Brother, thank you! Totally understand it and it works great.

Comment: Awesome. Makes me happy that you're happy.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you use jquery simple ajax request?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "file.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function() {
            // on success here
        }
    });
});
```